Is there documented FCC/Congressional reasoning behind restricting Tech licensees to CW on HF?
Is anyone aware of documented Congressional/FCC reasoning behind restricting Technician licensees to CW on HF?
I'm not (yet) advocating for a change or to keep status quo, rather am trying to understand why this particular Chesterton's Fence exists.
I'm specifically interested in documented reasoning by the governing authorities, not trying to solicit opinions 

In 2018, the ARRL petitioned the FCC to expand HF privileges for Technicians, including more data and phone privileges (RM-11828). This petition, 30 pages long, includes lots of historical background that you might find useful. You can find it here:
https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/search/search-filings/filing/1022823795806
If you search on the FCC website, you will find many follow-on documents (e.g. comments).
I believe this topic got drawn into the big debate over data mode baud rate, and also COVID came about and affected work in progress. As far as I know, nothing is happening on it now. It might be that the ARRL will have to restart it with the FCC. After their experience with the digital mode baud rate issue, the ARRL might not be eager to take on another controversial issue.
